# Jackson (JSON) : Serializing an instance variable with different name based on underlying implementation

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, fasterxml

I have a class(Message) which has some instance variables. One of these variable is of type interface(MessageContent). During serializing this class to json, I want to serialize this variable(content) with a name depending on the implementation. Below is code snippet for details:

```
public class Message {
    private String from;
    private String to;
    private MessageContent content;
    // Getters & setters
}

public interface MessageContent {}

public class VideoMessage implements MessageContent {
    private String videoUrl;
    // Getters & setters
}

public class ImageMessage implements MessageContent {
    private String imageUrl;
    // Getters & setters
}
```

My requirement is that when Message is serialized and content is of type VideoMessage, than serialized json should be:

{
"from":123,
"to":345,
**"video"**: {
"videoUrl":"some url"
}
}

And when content is of type ImageMessage, serailized json should be like:

{
"from":123,
"to":345,
**"image"**: {
"imageUrl":"some url"
}
}

How is it possible via fasterxml jackson? I am using ObjectMapper's writeValueAsString method, but not sure how to achieve this.
I tried annotating ImageMessage and VideoMessage with annotations like @JsonTypeName & @JsonTypeInfo but not sure if that's possible by them.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
public class Message {
    private String from;
    private String to;
}

public class VideoMessage extends Message {
    private MessageContent video;
}

public class ImageMessage extends Message {
    private MessageContent image;
}

public interface MessageContent {}

public class VideoContent implements MessageContent {
    private String videoUrl;
}

public class ImageContent implements MessageContent {
    private String imageUrl;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution would work. Still curious if there's any jackson way to achieve the same as changing the design would be last option. It would require creating some extra classes for each message type whereas they just differ in their content type(MessageContent). We usually create object of Message everywhere, and depending on some condition, set it's content to VideoContent, ImageContent, AudioContent, PDFContent or any other content(there are 10 implementations of MessageContent) type we have in our system.

Comment: This solution is much cleaner than any framework dependent, reflection-riddled mapping trick. An idea of O-O is that when looking at a class you don't need to know anything about its extensions. The approach you are after would entail exactly that: marking up the Message.content field in a way that depends on the available sub classes. That said, I did not easily find a way to find a mapping solution. Maybe the designers of the Jackson framework also thought it wasn't a good idea...